# Troubleshooting Memory Leak in JInput: Windows Not Getting Destroyed Properly

Tags: java, c, winapi, resource-leak, jinput

##### Background

I'm working on implementing controller hot swapping in `JInput` and have encountered a memory leak. I've made some progress on the Java side, which is documented in this [PR](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/pull/82), but there seems to be a lingering problem on the native C side, specifically regarding window creation and destruction.

The full background of the issue can be found [here](https://github.com/Valkryst/VController/issues/6).

##### Issue Description

In the `JInput` library, joystick input on Windows involves creating and destroying windows. This process is handled by the native C code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/blob/master/plugins/windows/src/main/native/net_java_games_input_DummyWindow.c).
The problem arises when I attempt to destroy these windows using `DestroyWindow`. Even after calling this function, the hidden windows continue to appear in tools such as `WinLister` and `Spy++` and accumulate in memory causing a resource leak.

##### What I've Tried

1. I've attempted to process all remaining messages for the windows before destroying them.
2. I've made sure that both creation and destruction are performed by the same thread.
3. I've checked the return value of DestroyWindow and verified that it is not reporting any errors by calling GetLastError.

An interesting observation is that when I attempt to call DestroyWindow again with the same handle, it returns error code 1400, indicating an invalid handle.

Comment: DestroyWindow sends  WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY messages to the window in question. What the window does then depends on its code. If its not destroyed it probably means it doesn't want to die or it doesn't (or can't) process these messages ("someone" must pump them). Do you know/have the code to this window and the message pump?

Comment: [This](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/blob/f4085f5542f273fe830e784d5a610ab5a534dc3d/plugins/windows/src/main/native/raw/net_java_games_input_RawInputEventQueue.c) should be the relevant part in the original code. 

I've [modified](https://github.com/Marko19907/jinput-hotswap-fix/blob/ddabe2bad5a479345cb8a8e8716a5f733e2e1b17/plugins/windows/src/main/native/raw/net_java_games_input_RawInputEventQueue.c) this slightly in my own fork of `JInput` to break the `GetMessage` with `PostMessage` so that I can stop the controller polling.

Comment: That code looks quite funky in Windows term :-) You should have a window procedure, not handle messages directly using GetMessage. It should look like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmessage#return-value https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/using-window-procedures

Comment: Thanks, I'll try to reimplement it like that

Comment: Also see [The dangers of filtering window messages](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20050209-00/?p=36493).

Comment: I've now rewritten it with the Window Procedures in [this](https://github.com/jinput/jinput/blob/9e496e28a6f3a0faf7f0c347f8853ae9cd86a486/plugins/windows/src/main/native/net_java_games_input_DummyWindow.c) branch like you all suggested but it's still behaving the same, the input works but it's again spawning a bunch of windows and not removing them.

Comment: There's nothing that would break the (horrible) `while (PeekMessage())` loop. The code will just continue to burn through an entire CPU core and never reach the `DestroyWindow()` call. I'm not confident that `throwIOException()` from the window procedure will end well, and utterly confused why there is a call to `DefWindowProc` following `throwIOException`.

Comment: Unfortunately, the proposed solution doesn’t seem to resolve the issue; the windows persist. It’s unclear whether `throwIOException()` is functioning as expected within this context. If it doesn’t behave like a typical throw, the execution could indeed continue to the subsequent line. This could explain why `DefWindowProc` is being called after `throwIOException()`. Struggling to find any docs on this.

Comment: Java_net_java_games_input_DummyWindow_nDestroy comment shows misconception. You don't "Make sure the window has no more messages before it gets killed", you pump all messages and then some special messages that are sent/pumped/processed ask the window to close/destroy. See this example here of processing raw input https://gist.github.com/petersvp/5e0a60c3d6e1ba6b7685807abf4ad799 it's not perfect but it works and closes the window (note the usage of GetMessage pump vs Peek, PostThreadMessage to get out of the loop, and the HWND_MESSAGE window)